# convert byte array to string without interpreting the bytes?

Tags: python, arrays, decode

I have a GSM date/time stamp from a PDU encoded SMS it is formatted as so

\x90,\x21,\x51,\x91,\x40,\x33

format yy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss

I have read them from a binary file into a byte array. I want to convert them to a string but without doing any decoding I want to end up with a string that contains 902151914033. I then need to reverse each 2 characters in the string.

Can anyone give me some pointers?
Many Thanks

Comment: So in your input, 0x90 or '\x90' represents the year (20)09, 0x21 represents the month 12, 0x51 represents the day 15, etc??? What brilliant mind devised that encoding scheme?

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started:

```
>>> s = b'\x90\x21\x51\x91\x40\x33'
>>> lst = [hex(z)[2:] for z in s]
>>> lst
['90', '21', '51', '91', '40', '33']

>>> string = ''.join(hex(z)[3:1:-1] for z in s)
>>> string
'091215190433'
```

Answer (score 5):

To convert to hex:

`hexdata = ''.join('%02x' % ord(byte) for byte in bindata)`

To reverse every other hex character (if I'm understanding correctly):

`hexdata = ''.join(('%02x' % ord(byte))[::-1] for byte in bindata)`

Comment: Latest Python has a better (IMO) string formatting: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: @lpthnc: matter of taste, really. Keep it as simple and as readable as possible :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is that you *do* want to do some processing! The unprocessed bytes are most easily represented as characters.

I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
r = ''
for num in array:
    r += '%2X' % num
return r
```

Which I'm sure could be wrapped up in an anonymous function, if necessary.

Comment: @Autopulated: fixed your answer to the first question, `'\x90'` is `chr(0x90)` and not `chr(90)`. The LC solutions are better though.

Answer (score 0):

If, in your question, the string you have provided is the literal set of bytes (as ascii) including the \ and , and you wish to strip them out you could use the binascii module and str.replace:

```
import binascii
qp = binascii.b2a_qp( bunchabytes )
plainstring = qp.replace( '\\x', '' ).replace( ',', '' )
```

The resultant plainstring will consist of only the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
switcher= dict(
    (n1*16 + n2, n2*16 + n1)
    for n1 in range(16)
    for n2 in range(16)
)

def nibble_switcher(bindata):
    return type(bindata)(switcher[i] for i in bindata)
    # will work with many types, not only bytearray

def nibble_switcher_as_hex_string(bindata):
    return ''.join("%02x" % i for i in nibble_switcher(bindata))
```